# Why am I getting this strange error when trying to add a duplicate object to a std::set?

Tags: c++, set, duplicates

Here is the code that is giving me trouble:

```
Relation* Relation::relation_union(Relation* r) {
    std::set<Tuple*>::iterator it1;
    for (it1 = tuples.begin(); it1 != tuples.end(); it1++) {                                          
        r->tuples.insert(*it1);         //this is where i insert into the set              
    }
    return r;
}
```

I can't figure out why this is happening for the life of me. I get a core dump with this code.

The following code works fine to order tuples in my set alphabetically (which are vectors of strings), but I think it's the source of my error because it doesn't know what to do when every element is the same:

**EDIT** Made changes to code.

```
struct comp {
    bool operator ()(const Tuple * lt, const Tuple * rt) {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < lt->values.size(); i++) {
            std::string strl = lt->values[i];
            std::string strr = rt->values[i];
            if (strl != strr) {
                return (strl < strr); // compares with the length
            }
        }
            return false;
    }

};
```

'tuples' comes from the following code:

```
Relation(){
        name = "";
        schema = new Schema();
        tuples = std::set<Tuple*, comp>();
        domain = std::set<std::string>();
    }

    std::string name;
    Schema* schema;
    std::set<Tuple*, comp> tuples;
    std::set<std::string> domain;
}
```

Here is my stack backtrace - it wasn't very helpful for me:

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff753b425 in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff753b425 in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff753eb8b in abort () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff7b9169d in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff7b8f846 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff7b8f873 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff7b8f96e in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007ffff7b3c987 in std::__throw_out_of_range(char const*) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x00007ffff7b7a453 in std::string::substr(unsigned long, unsigned long) const () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#8  0x000000000040d889 in Input::getTokensValue (this=0x630460) at Input.cpp:91
#9  0x000000000040e812 in Lex::emit (this=0x7fffffffe130, tokenType=UNDEFINED) at Lex.cpp:268
#10 0x000000000040e12d in Lex::nextState (this=0x7fffffffe130) at Lex.cpp:106
#11 0x000000000040e026 in Lex::generateTokens (this=0x7fffffffe130, input=0x630460) at Lex.cpp:85
#12 0x000000000040da20 in Lex::Lex (this=0x7fffffffe130, filename=0x0) at Lex.cpp:17
#13 0x000000000040ea3e in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe248) at main.cpp:7
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Half the point of `std::set` is that it doesn't store duplicates. Is there some problem with having a set of `Tuple` instead of those pointers?

Comment: What does `comp::operator()` return if all values are equal?

Comment: In addition to @AlexChamberlain, turn up your warning level.

Comment: It doesn't return anything if every value is equal - what should it return? I've tried several things but nothing has worked.

Comment: @amorimluc, Well, it has to return something. If it doesn't, have fun with your undefined behaviour.

Comment: @chris If a set stores pointers, does it not check for duplicates then?

Comment: @amorimluc, Yes, it would just check for duplicate pointers. I really don't see why those pointers are there in the first place, though, as you're just rewriting the code not to let duplicate objects in.

Comment: Think we need to see where you insert into the set.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain I've added a comment indicating where I insert to the set. That't exactly the place I get the core dump when trying to insert a duplicate.

Comment: Sorry, I meant where does `tuples` get initialised?

Comment: I've added another code snippet to show where tuples comes from.

Comment: I think, this is the time (after ~1 hour) to provide the exact error message you get.

Comment: This is getting slow... where do you insert stuff into `tuples`?

Comment: @SChepurin In all fairness, it's a core dump. A `gdb` stack trace would be useful, however.

Comment: I add and change my 'tuples' objects all over my code - and my code is getting pretty large. I'm writing a datalog interpreter and this portion of my code does projection, renaming, and other databse operations. I'll paste my stack backtrace in a sec.

Comment: @Alex Chamberlain - i guess, this does not imply that 'i get a core dump' is enough to describe 'this strange error'. when you are stuck every bit of information is helpful.

Comment: Stick it in `valgrind`; I'm guessing you have dangling pointers.

Comment: I figured it out - I thought I was replacing an element by inserting another one at its spot, but the original element was just getting pushed ahead. This was the source of my error. I appreciate everyone's help.

Comment: Now you see - "..._throw_out_of_range(char const*)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool operator ()(const Tuple * lt, const Tuple * rt) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < lt->values.size(); i++) {
        std::string strl = lt->values[i];
        std::string strr = rt->values[i];
        if (strl != strr) {
            return (strl < strr); // compares with the length
        }

    }
    return false;//EDIT
 }
```

Comment: I added that to my code but I'm still getting a core dump when I try to add a duplicate object... What could be causing this?

Comment: This wasn't the source of my error, but a necessary portion for my code to function correctly. Thx

Answer (score 2):

`comp::operator()` should return `false` if all values are equal.

```
struct comp {
    bool operator ()(const Tuple * lt, const Tuple * rt) {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < lt->values.size(); i++) {
            std::string strl = lt->values[i];
            std::string strr = rt->values[i];
            if (strl != strr) {
                return (strl < strr); // compares with the length
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison operator expects the 'values' member of both operands to have the same size. If rt->values is shorter than lt->values, you'll get anohter out-of-bounds error (but the one in question is not coming from here).